# How to adapt svg position in small displays?

Tags: html, css

I have a block with an SVG image inside

```css
.footer_about {
  background: #fdebd2;
  color: #222;
  padding: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer_about .svg-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -52px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_about">
  <svg class="svg-top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1400 48" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
            <path d="M1400 0l-55 12-23 10-23 4-6-1-9 1-5 2-24 8h-11l-18-5-11-1-10-1h-7l-8 3-8 1-14-4v1l-3 1-9-5-3-1-17 2-10-1-9-1-8 1-7 1-2 1h-13l-2-1-13-2h-20l-11 2-14 3h-18l-10 1-3-1-2-1-4-1h-4l-16 1h-2l-7-1h-6l-8 1-6-2-5-1-2 1-20-1-10 2h-6l-11-1-9-1h-4l-3 1-19 1h-19l-3-1-11 1h-2l-7 3h-23l-3 1h-19l-16-1-17 1h-8l-2-1-20-2-4 1-4-1h-2l-12 1-2 1h-13l-9 1h-4l-6-1-10 1-9-1h-15l-9 2-12-2-12-2-3 2-5 2-11-3-6 1h-6l-28 1-5 2h-33l-3 1-4 2h-17l-5 1-4-1-7-1h-5l-4 1-13 3-2-2-2-1h-15l-22-1h-2l-11 1h-5l-2-1h-19l-9 1-6-1h-2l-9 2-15 2h-4l-12 1h-25l-12 1-7 1h-4l-4 1h-4l-4 1h-20l-3-1h-7l-1-1v-4l-1 1h-2l-9 1-2 2-6 2-7 1-5 2h-2l-3-2-8-1h-4l-11 3h-1l-3-2-11-3-20-6-9-3h-3l-9 2h-5l-11-4-13-3-11-15-21-4L0 0h1400z"></path>
        </svg>
</div>
```

In the small displays I get empty white space between the parent block and SVG:

[image]

How to fix SVG on the top of a parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close to it. But don't use pixel values with `top` in this specific situation. Instead, use percentage values with `transform` property to achieve the desired result as shown below.

```
transform: translate(0%, -100%) rotate(180deg);
```

The above line of code works like this:

1. `translate(0%, -100%)` translates your svg on Y-axis upto a value equal to the height of svg itself. This keeps the svg sticking to the top of the footer.
2. `rotate(180deg)` flips it vertically.

Complete Code:

```css
.footer_about {
  background: #fdebd2;
  color: #222;
  padding: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer_about .svg-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, -100%) rotate(180deg);    
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_about">
  <svg class="svg-top" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1400 48" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
    <path d="M1400 0l-55 12-23 10-23 4-6-1-9 1-5 2-24 8h-11l-18-5-11-1-10-1h-7l-8 3-8 1-14-4v1l-3 1-9-5-3-1-17 2-10-1-9-1-8 1-7 1-2 1h-13l-2-1-13-2h-20l-11 2-14 3h-18l-10 1-3-1-2-1-4-1h-4l-16 1h-2l-7-1h-6l-8 1-6-2-5-1-2 1-20-1-10 2h-6l-11-1-9-1h-4l-3 1-19 1h-19l-3-1-11 1h-2l-7 3h-23l-3 1h-19l-16-1-17 1h-8l-2-1-20-2-4 1-4-1h-2l-12 1-2 1h-13l-9 1h-4l-6-1-10 1-9-1h-15l-9 2-12-2-12-2-3 2-5 2-11-3-6 1h-6l-28 1-5 2h-33l-3 1-4 2h-17l-5 1-4-1-7-1h-5l-4 1-13 3-2-2-2-1h-15l-22-1h-2l-11 1h-5l-2-1h-19l-9 1-6-1h-2l-9 2-15 2h-4l-12 1h-25l-12 1-7 1h-4l-4 1h-4l-4 1h-20l-3-1h-7l-1-1v-4l-1 1h-2l-9 1-2 2-6 2-7 1-5 2h-2l-3-2-8-1h-4l-11 3h-1l-3-2-11-3-20-6-9-3h-3l-9 2h-5l-11-4-13-3-11-15-21-4L0 0h1400z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```